# Expression.SwitchCase with C# 7 pattern matching

Tags: .net, linq-expressions, c#-7.0

I want to dynamically build an `Expression` tree in C# that represents this code:

```
switch (x)
{
    case A1 cx: Handle(cx); break;
    case A2 cx: Handle(cx); break;
}
```

So far I have something like this:

```
Expression.Switch(xParameterExpression,
    Expression.SwitchCase(
        method1CallExpression, /* test value expression - what to put here ?? */),
    Expression.SwitchCase(
        method2CallExpression, /* test value expression - what to put here ?? */));
```

I could also use the `Expression.TypeAs` but it doesn't seem to work.  I suspect I need an expression similar to the `if (x is A1 cx) { }` conditional rather than the `var cx = x as A1;`.

I realise these are new C# 7.0 features but wondered if all new language features are added to Expressions?

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed code example please, which more clearly shows what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My use case is to create a dynamic method/compiled delegate containing the switch statements. I haven't got much further than that for a code example but it will allow me to construct and execute a basic switch statement all at runtime.

Comment: `System.Linq.Expressions` package hasn't been updated since Nov 2016 so I assume it doesn't contain the new C# 7.0 language support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the C# 7.0 feature have support in expression trees at this point. You will find a number of compiler Pull Requests that explicitly [handle this](https://github.com/AlekseyTs/roslyn/commits/100afa51a01a81927796adb75627149190b209cd/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/DiagnosticsPass_ExpressionTrees.cs) (produce a diagnostic if you tried).

If this is important to you, I'd suggest you file an issue on the Roslyn repo (I couldn't find an existing one) and gather some support.